# Salesforce Apex class update the region field in contact record

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

I am trying to update region field based on country of residence and nationality, for example if nationality is UK, and country to resident is UK then country of region should be UK as well but it is coming up as empty.

```java
static void insertOrUpdateContactRegion(List<Contact> contactsToUpdateOrInsert){
        try{
            /*Calling Utility method to retrieve the map of country and corresponding region*/
            Map<String,String> mapCountryRegion = CU_GeneralUtility.getCountryRegionMap();
            /*Calling a Utility Method to Convert Domicile Country Code to Country Region for Contact.*/
            Map<String,String> mapOfDomicileCodeToCountryLabel=CU_GeneralUtility.getMapOfPicklistValuesToLabel(CU_GlobalConstants.OBJECT_API_NAME_CONTACT,CU_GlobalConstants.FIELD_DOMICILE_COUNTRY_CODE);        
            for (Contact contact : contactsToUpdateOrInsert)
            {
                System.debug('mapCountryRegion: '+mapCountryRegion);
                if(mapCountryRegion!=null && mapOfDomicileCodeToCountryLabel!=null && mapOfDomicileCodeToCountryLabel.containsKey(contact.Domicile_Country_Code__c)){
                    System.debug('in if .CU_Region__c: ');    
                    if(mapCountryRegion.get(mapOfDomicileCodeToCountryLabel.get(contact.Domicile_Country_Code__c)) != null ){
                        contact.CU_Region__c= mapCountryRegion.get(mapOfDomicileCodeToCountryLabel.get(contact.Domicile_Country_Code__c));
                    }
                }
                System.debug('contact.CU_Region__c: '+contact.CU_Region__c);                
            }            
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Map<String,Object> mapErrorInfo= CU_BaseErrorHandler.formatException(CU_GlobalConstants.CLASS_NAME_BG_CONTACT_UTILS,CU_GlobalConstants.METHOD_NAME_insertOrUpdateContactRegion,CU_GlobalConstants.SEVERITY_MEDIUM,ex,null,ex.getTypeName()+'>>>'+ex.getMessage());
            CU_ApplicationErrorHandler.createErrorLogRecord(JSON.serialize(mapErrorInfo));
        }
    }
```

Map of picklist value to label

```java
 public static Map<String,String> getMapOfPicklistValuesToLabel(String associatedObjName, String fieldAPIName){
        Map<String,String> mapOfPickListValueToLabels=new Map<String,String>();
        try{
            List<String> pickListValuesList= new List<String>();
            Schema.SObjectType objectResults = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(associatedObjName);
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = objectResults.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(fieldAPIName).getDescribe();
            List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
            for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickListVal : ple){
                mapOfPickListValueToLabels.put(pickListVal.getValue(), pickListVal.getLabel());
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Map<String,Object> mapErrorInfo= CU_BaseErrorHandler.formatException(CU_GlobalConstants.CLASS_NAME_CU_GeneralUtility,CU_GlobalConstants.METHOD_NAME_getMapOfPicklistValuesToLabel,CU_GlobalConstants.SEVERITY_MEDIUM,ex,null,ex.getTypeName()+'>>>'+ex.getMessage());
            CU_ApplicationErrorHandler.createErrorLogRecord(JSON.serialize(mapErrorInfo));
        }       
        return mapOfPickListValueToLabels;
    }
```

Getting Country Region

```java
public static Map<String,String> getCountryRegionMap() 
{
    //US-2789 - optimization
    if(mapRegions == null) {
        mapRegions = new Map<String,String>();
        
        // query the region mapping metadata to return all countries and regions
        List<Region_Mapping__mdt> lstRegionMetadata =  [SELECT Id, country__c, region__c 
                                                        FROM Region_Mapping__mdt limit 1000];
        
        // assign the region mapping metadata to a map
        for (Region_Mapping__mdt region : lstRegionMetadata)
        {
            mapRegions.put(region.country__c,region.region__c);
        }
    }

    return mapRegions; //return the map
}
```

Comment: could you point out where and what is failing? any debug logs you have setup to trace the origin of the behavior? etc etc..

Comment: note that your exception handler in `getMapOfPicklistValuesToLabel` is eating the error -- it would be better if it threw an exception for the caller to handle.
Your debug statements as shown should provide insight into the issue - note that map keys are case sensitive